# Google Sheets Query / Date formula issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Would really appreciate some help with this Google Sheets formula.

I'm trying to pull up events that occur on `=Today() using a query formula, but it just isn't working. The purpose for this is to have a kind of calendar on my dashboard.

AO is the column that holds the dates for events. BG is the client's name.

```
=QUERY(clients,"SELECT BG, AP, AQ, AR WHERE AO = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately, it contains sensitive info. I'll try to replicate it though.  Also, if it helps, currently the formula is extracting whatever the first row on the sheet is, instead of extracting the rows that match the current date

Comment: You can remove the sensitive info and keep the AO and another column only. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CCA22ByvYhy2Qq0cheShjuwADypLyZh3ES4VsryoajM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The problem lies with the optional argument in QUERY function which is set to 1 in your current formula. Setting it to 1 will force the query to return a value, thus, having the first row in the data set as the result.

### Solution

You should set the said optional argument to 0. Apply to both TODAY and TOMORROW tables. Please see formula below:

```
=QUERY(courtdates,"SELECT BV, AR, BO WHERE BN = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much! This worked. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I'd appreciate it if you will accept/upvote the answer so that other users will see the solution to their problem if ever they encounter the same one. :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers